# Google Cloud Datastore: Full text search?

Tags: full-text-search, google-cloud-datastore

I am developing a database app using Google Cloud Datastore but don't see any built-in way of doing full-text search on fields.  Is there a google-cloud-native solution?

The alternative I see is either:

1. Do full text search application side (read in each row, find matches)
2. dupe the fields that need to be full-text-indexed into some other product like Google Cloud Sql (mysql) and use it's full-text-search capabilities instead.

Answer (score 8):

You might want to look into the [App Engine search API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/) as an alternative to duplicating fields into Cloud SQL for full text search.

You still need to duplicate the data into documents/indexes but you only [pay per queries and storage.](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing#search_pricing)

Comment: thx for links @danielx - Q is that search suitable for 1MB text content?

Comment: @BGBruno Search API has a limit of 1 MB for each document.